# Magento Static Block is at a Different Place on Internet Explorer than on Chrome, Firefox

Tags: php, internet-explorer, magento, static-block

I created 3 static blocks ('vert_nav_link', 'social_network', and 'vert_goto_hapi') on a magento site and placed them on the left column (sidebar).  On Chrome, Firefox and Safari, they are all shown on the left sidebar. On IE 8, the last static block ends up at the main column.  Not sure why, since I used the same coding on all three.  Here is the php code,

```
<div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
   <div class="main">
       <div class="col-main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
       </div>
       <div class="col-left sidebar">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('vert_nav_link')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('social_network')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('vert_goto_hapi')->toHtml(); ?>     
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any insight will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check those:

*HTML for last block is valid. Means there are no such things like:

```
 <span</span>
```

*Change the left block height. It might be simply css problem. So try to increase left block height and might be put float left on this block, but I am not sure, because I am not CSS guru. Also display:inline-block or inline might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  After trying those things, I decided to just add the content of the 2nd static block to the first static block, and it appears to work out well.  It is not the best practice, but it did work.  Thank you once again.